# Polling multiple resources using RxJS in angular 5

Tags: typescript, rxjs, operators, angular5

I have a requirement of polling multiple resources over time. Each time I start polling it should add it in some kind of poll **pool**. if any of the request meets some criteria then I have to take that out of my pool. How can we achieve this using rxjs cool operators?

Comment: Can you add some examples of input and desired ouput for each input in your question ?

Comment: Generally speaking you do not use RxJs for polling, rather you use RxJs to avoid polling and do stuff when somebody pushes you something. Anyways, this is just a bit of bla bla. An example of what you can achieve would help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question like that, that you want to poll a list of ressources.

interval(timer) for the timed polling and takeUntil() / takeWhile() to end a subscription could be your thing then.

```
let pollSubscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription()

let requestUrl = 'http://bestResourceever.com'
let polltime = 5000; // Timer for polling

this.addNewPoll(requestUrl, polltime);


addNewPoll(url, timer){
    this.pollSubscriptions.add(
        interval(timer).pipe(
            switchMap(()=> this.http.get(url) ),
            tap(data => this.writeDateSomewhere(data) ),
            takeUntil( data => this.shouldPollingBeStopped(data) )
        ).subscribe()
    )
}
```

I added a "pollSubscription.add()" in the case that you want to unsubscribe all polling Subscriptions at once (this.pollSubscriptions.unsubscribe() )

warm regards

Comment: Thanks a lot @JanRecker. This looks promising.. Will try it out for sure...
Out of curiosity I am just asking the method "this.shouldPollingBeStopped(data)" will stop on resource pooling right whose condition satisfied  not the others right?

Comment: takeUntil will unsubscribe from the current stream when it get´s a "true" from the method. So it will only unsubscribe for that one polling stream. But still here it is ONE Method for all polls, so even if every poll is stoped for itself, the logic behind it is the same.
To make it more generic, you could give "addNewPoll" a function as a parameter, that function could then be uses as "shouldPollingBeStopped" function. Then you are able to have different takeUntil condition implementations per polling stream

Comment: Thanks @JanRecker. But I see takeUntil accepts an observable. I want to stop my polling if my (data) => data.isOk === true;

how can I achieve this?

Comment: can we use takeWhile:
addNewPoll(url, timer){
    this.pollSubscriptions.add(
        interval(timer).pipe(
            switchMap(()=> this.http.get(url) ),
            tap(data => this.writeDateSomewhere(data) ),
            takeWhile( data => data.isOk != true )
        ).subscribe()
    )
}

Comment: Yes, in your case, you want to react on the basis of your events IN your stream, then takeWhile() is the way to go. Sorry, i missed that one.

Comment: I tried implementing this...Seems my takeWhile method never gets hit... Can u plz help?

Comment: Could you post your code, so that i can take a look ? Than i would like to try.

Comment: Sorry @JanRecker it was a miss from my side. Works perfectly.. Can you help me with 2 more enhancements:
1. How can I retry for 3 times(in a delay of 3 secs) if call fails.. Note we have Observable.timer.
2. Can we make only distinct urls being polled?

Working code:
        this.pollSubscriptions.add(observableTimer(0, timer).pipe(
            switchMap(() => this.http.get<T>(url).pipe(
                catchError((error: any) => empty()))),
            tap(updateStatus),
            takeWhile(data => pollWhileCondition(data)))
            .subscribe());

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be worth a new question :-) ---- Try "retryWhen" (see first example here: "https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html" ).
--- Every URL you throw in your poll-Subscription will be polled, every other will not.  You could possibly work with "filter" ( https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html " ) but i would seperate "polled" and "normal" url´s upfront.